# Twilio webhooks with dynamic IP - Can I poll?

Tags: twilio

We have a situation where our server is located on a mobile trailer using AT&T broadband. AT&T is double NAT'd so there is no way for me to open any ports and allow inbound traffic in.

(We are looking into static IPs but could be a long time coming.)

Is it possible to make a call to twilio to say "give me any new messages from this date"  Or is it all based on the webhooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yes!  You can use the REST API with date filters to get a list of messages.  This is what that would look like in Node:

```
client.messages
  .list({
     dateSentBefore: new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
     dateSentAfter: new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
     limit: 20
   })
  .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.sid)));
```

You can find a more complete Node sample plus samples in other languages [in our docs](http://%20https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource?code-sample=code-read-list-messages-filter-by-a-period-of-time&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does this also work for the messaging service? We are using the Messaging Service, Notify, &, Passthrough API so we can send out blocks of messages at a time.  I see though that the code is dateSENT.  How do I look for date received?   I really only care about inbound messages.

Comment: I realize this will get ALL of the messages.  I just need to also filter by the TO: address

Comment: The messages API accepts multiple filters including `To`, `From` and `DateSent` which are outline in our docs:https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource?code-sample=code-read-list-messages-matching-filter-criteria&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#read-multiple-message-resources

Answer (score 0):

Is this for SMS?  You ordinarily do not need a server to make HTTP requests to a REST API.  I can't find it after a cursory look in their docs, but what you are looking for is a page that lists all the HTTP endpoints and their cognate request method. From there, use a library like `requests` or `http.client` or `urllib` to send the requests.

Edit: this post is geared for the Pythonistas

Comment: It is for SMS. I know I don’t need a “server”. But it’s my server that is making the calls to the REST API.